# Android: TextView Background/Text Color Loop

Tags: android, ios, xcode, loops

ATTENTION: This question requires knowledge of iOS development to answer.

I have created a screen flash feature for an app I'm building within the Xcode environment. The screen flashes as follows:

Background white, with red text....background red, with white text, at an interval of 0.25 sec.

The flash occurs continuously until the user taps on the screen to move forward in the app.
Here is the code I used to accomplish this:

```
    @interface OrderCashButtonSignal : UIViewController

 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *orderCashLabel;
 @property (strong, nonatomic) NSTimer *colorTimer;


 @end

    - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
[super viewDidLoad];

self.orderCashLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.orderCashLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
self.colorTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.25 target:self   selector:@selector(changeColor) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

(void)changeColor{

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{

    if ([self.orderCashLabel.backgroundColor isEqual:[UIColor whiteColor]]&&[self.orderCashLabel.textColor isEqual:[UIColor redColor]]) {
        self.orderCashLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        self.orderCashLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
    else{

        self.orderCashLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.orderCashLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];

    }


 }];


  }
```

I have tried to mimic this behavior in Eclipse for my Android version of this app, but can't figure out how to implement a timer, and changeColor method together the way I've done it in Xcode. I understand that they are different languages, and the methods are going to be different. I thought I might be able to find my way around the Android framework, and solve my problem, but I have failed miserably. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Uhh, where's your Android code that you're having problems with?

Comment: I didn't have any respectable android code to insert. I played with some methods, but came up with nothing good. So, I just added the iOS code to give an example of what I was trying to accomplish. Sorry!

Comment: Didn't the anwser help you?

Comment: Sorry EMarci15, I didn't get to play with your code until yesterday; and yes, it did help me! BIG thanks to you! I had an idea of what was needed, but had no idea how to put it together. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables:

```
Timer timer = new timer();
    boolean b = true;
```

Set in xml `android:background` property to `#FFFFFF` and `android:textColor` to `#FF0000`.
Into onCreate() insert:

```
timerStep = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  @Override
                  public void run() {
                    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.YourDefinedTextViewID);
                if (b) {
                    t.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    t.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    b=false;
                } else {
                    t.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                    t.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    b=true;
                }
                }
            }
        }
};
timer.schedule(timerStep,250,250);
```